# Passing data to various view controllers via delegate

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, appdelegate

Struggling to learn the basics of passing data via `delegates`. I am trying to pass a string from my `viewController` to my `viewController2` and print it. I am getting the error:

> > "Type `ViewController2` has no member `delagate`"  in my `view controller 2`.

I cannot figure out where I have gone wrong.

viewController 1:

```
protocol datadelagate {
    func printThisString(string: String)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: datadelagate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        delegate?.printThisString(string: "This was passed from first controller to second controller")
    }
}
```

This is my viewController 2:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController, datadelagate {

    func printThisString(string: String) {
        print(string)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ViewController2.delagate = self
        print(String.self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `ViewController2` to print some value from `ViewController`, you might have to do it this way:

```
protocol datadelagate {
    func printThisString(string: String)
    func getStringFromVC1() -> String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, datadelagate {

    let someString: String = "From VC1"

    func printThisString(string: String) {
        print(string)
    }

    func getStringFromVC1() -> String {
        return someString
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        ViewController2.delagate = self

    }
}
```

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    var delegate: datadelagate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //This is how something from VC2 is sent to VC1's scope.
        delegate?.printThisString(string: "Calling the delegate to print something from ViewController2 on first ViewController")

        //The below call gets you some value from VC1. (This is what you wanted, I belive...)
        print(delegate?.getStringFromVC1())
    }
}
```

Now for some explanation:

For simple understanding, assume a `delegate` as a person who does some specific job (`protocol`).

You have a `delegate'

You ask your delegate to work with your friend, and your friend acknowledges. (assigns your delegate by `You.delegate = self`, where self is your friend)

Now, through your `delegate`, you can do something with your friend, by asking your `delegate` to do some job (defined in `protocol`).

---

**EDIT**

*The code above won't work, as non-static data members are trying to be accessed without creating an instance*

---

**Working code**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    static let sharedInstance = ViewController2()
    weak var delegate: DataDelagate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //This is how something from VC2 is sent to VC1's scope.
        delegate?.printThis(string: "Calling the delegate to print something from ViewController2 on first ViewController")

        //The below call gets you some value from VC1. (This is what you wanted, I belive...)
        print(delegate?.getStringFromVC1() ?? "s")
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    static let sharedInstance = ViewController2()
    var someString: String = "From VC1"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ViewController2.sharedInstance.delegate = self
    }
}
extension ViewController: DataDelagate {
    func printThis(string: String) {
        print(string)
    }

    func getStringFromVC1() -> String {
        return someString
    }
}

protocol DataDelagate: AnyObject {
    func printThis(string: String)
    func getStringFromVC1() -> String
}
```

Comment: This Presents the error "Instance member 'delegate' cannot be used on type 'ViewController2'" in view controller 1

Comment: @pete800, Yes. Like I said, for simplicity sake I wrote it so. It's because, the data members are being accessed without creating an instance. I'll add a full working code in the end of my post now.